# How to hide / display a forms with a combo box

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, forms

So hello everybody :D 
I don't know how to hide or show the form that I want between two feasible choice.

Etudiant --> studentForm

Employee --> employeeForm

what is happening is that although it changes form but when I press the submit button and not choosing my combox!
Yet the name of the selected combobox change much
I do not understand: 3
To achieve this I have exchanged the two forms ie the student form displays that of employee and vice versa ...

If I put the values logically there when the student form that appears and submit does nothing more
My code is coding with Django python

What is the problem in my jquery or my forms i don't know ?

**This is my template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends "polls/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Création d'un profil{% endblock %}
{% block bodyId %}userProfilePage{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        displayRightForm();
    });

    function displayRightForm() {
        if ($("#profileType").val() == 'employee') {
            $('#employeeForm').hide();
            $('#studentForm').show();
        } else {
            $('#studentForm').hide();
            $('#employeeForm').show();
        }
    }
$('select').on('change', function() {
    displayRightForm();
});
</script>


<h1>Création d'un compte</h1>
<form>
    <p>
        <label>Vous êtes :</label>
        <select id="profileType">
            <option value="student" {% if studentForm.is_bound %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Étudiant</option>
            <option value="employee" {% if employeeForm.is_bound %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Employé</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</form>

<form action="register" method="GET" id="employeeForm">
    {{ employeeForm.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="profileType" value="employee" />
        <input type="submit" value="Créer un compte" />     
    </p>
</form>

<form action="register" method="GET" id="studentForm">
    {{ studentForm.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="profileType" value="student" />
        <input type="submit" value="Créer un compte" />
    </p>
</form>

<div id="two">


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css"/>

{% endblock %}
```

**I have try this method :**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').on('change', function() {
        if(this.value == 'student')
      {
        $("#student").show();
        $("#employee").hide();
      }
        else if(this.value == 'employee')
      {
        $("#employee").show();
        $("#student").hide();

      }
    });
});
</script>
```

But don't work again ...

Comment: did you see my answer?? I think it works as you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  action();
  $(".disabler").on("change", action);



});

function action() {

  var checked = $(".disabler").prop("checked");

  if (checked) {
    $(".showable").removeClass("hidden");
  } else {
    $(".showable").addClass("hidden");

  }

}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.form{
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Show form
<input class="disabler" type="checkbox">

<div class="showable">
  <h2>Form</h2>
  
  <form class="form">
  Name <input type="text">
  </form>
  
</div>
```

Comment: @Jérémy Legendre : It is working fine please use this.